# ios global background thread never executed

Tags: ios, multithreading, sdwebimage

I am using the following code to load images in a background thread:

```
NSArray *visibleCells = [self.collectionView visibleCells];
for (CCell *cell in visibleCells)
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"loading cell: %lld", cell.uniqueID);
        [[SDWebImageManager sharedManager] downloadImageWithURL:cell.photoURL options:SDWebImageRetryFailed progress:nil
                                              completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
        //...
```

This runs ok for a few minutes, but then the background thread completely stops being executed, and I must force close and restart to get it to work again.

If I put a break point at `dispatch_async`, I see that it gets called, but I never see the log printed out.

Is there a reason that the background task is never executed? Could `SDWebImageManager` be tying up the thread? If so, is there any way to prevent this from happening?

UPDATE:

I tried changing to this:

```
NSLog(@"adding to background");
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    NSLog(@"loading in background");
    NSArray *visibleCells = [self.collectionView visibleCells];
    for (CCell *cell in visibleCells) {
```

But the same thing happened - I see "adding to background" stacking up, but never see "loading in background"

UPDATE:

I moved all the loading onto the main thread and it all worked ok. I'm not seeing any micro freezing / lagging either so I'll just stick with this option, however, I'm still wondering - does iOS stop running background tasks if the queue gets too long?

Comment: Did you try doing it the other way? HAve the for loop within the queue.

Comment: I tried it the other way but I still saw a lot of tasks stacking up but none of them ever ran. Does iOS stop running background tasks if the queue is too long?

Comment: if you dispatch to dispatch_get_main_queue(), does the code run?  This would help identify if the queue is the problem, or some other logic error exists

Comment: Why are you using dispatch_async anyway? SDWebImageManager is already asynchronous.

Comment: @Paulw11 good point. I originally wanted to offload as much as possible to fix choppy scrolling, but like I said in the latest update, its working fine on the main thread now. Back to the OP though - why would the background tasks never run?

Comment: @CSmith if I dispatch to main, the tasks consistently run ok. So its definitely something about the background thread

Comment: separate this code out, dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), see if its returning nil on you?